# Can we prove $a^{\log_bn} = n^{\log_ba}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Can we prove $$a^{\log_bn} = n^{\log_ba}?$$
I forget how to prove this theorem. I picked up one numbers for test, and they worked.

Comment: Hint: Start with the fact that $(log_bn)(log_ba) = (log_ba) (log_bn)$.

Comment: @fretty Thanks a lot! That works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take the log to the base $b$ of both sides.

Comment: This is deceptively simple. It's a good hint, but with it, one must be careful not to assume what one is trying to prove. See fretty's comment on the question for a safer starting point.

Answer (score 5):

$$a^{\log_b n}=n^{\log_n a \log_b n}=n^{\log_b a},\quad \text{using}\quad\log_n a=\frac{\log_b a}{\log_b n}.$$

Comment: You wrote "$\log_n a = \frac{log_b a}{log_b n}$" twice. Maybe delete "and ..." from your answer. Most helpful, btw.

Answer (score 5):

$a^{\log_b{n}}=n^{\log_b{a}}$/$\cdot$ $\log_a$

$\log_a a^{\log_b{n}}=\log_a n^{\log_b{a}}$

$\log_b{n}=\log_b{a} \log_a n$

$\log_b{n}=\frac{\log a}{\log b}\cdot\frac{\log n}{\log a}$

$\log_b{n}=\frac{\log n}{\log b}$

Answer (score 2):

use the following formula:
$$\log_a(b)=\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
a^{log_{b}{(n)}} 
\\(1) = b^{log_{b}{(a^{log_{b}{(n)}})}} 
\\(2) = b^{{log_{b}{(n)}}log_{b}{(a)}}
\\(3) = b^{{log_{b}{(a)}log_{b}{(n)}}}
\\(2) = b^{log_{b}{(n^{log_{b}{(a)}})}} 
\\(1) = n^{log_{b}{(a)}} 
$$

Given

(1) $$(b^{log_{b}x} = x)$$
(2) $$ log(a^x) = x*log(a)$$
(3) commutative property of multiplication $$ ab = ba $$