# An intuitive explanation or a proof of $n^{log_a b} = b^{log_a n}$

Tags: logarithms

I am reviewing logarithms and ran into this relationship
$n^{log_a b} = b^{log_a n}$

Could use some help understanding it

Comment: It follows from $\log_a(b) \log n = \log_a(n) \log b$. 
Since $\log_a(b) = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$ and $\log_a(n) = \frac{\log n}{\log a}$ it is true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we prove $a^{\log_bn} = n^{\log_ba}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262733/can-we-prove-a-log-bn-n-log-ba)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you https://math.stackexchange.com/users/983440/yooo for referencing a different answer. Searching by "n^{log_a b} = b^{log_a n}
" led me to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4199642/1068720 which gave me exactly what I was looking for.

The answer started with concepts and ended by explaining each operation.

This is the answer copied from [https://math.stackexchange.com/users/544150/mike's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/544150/mike%27s) post so people can see how good it is:

Are you familiar with the following: for any $c,d>1$: $d = c^{\log_c d}$. This follows from the definition of logarithm. I trust you also know the equation $e^{fg} = (e^f)^g$, for all positive e,f,g$

Thus:
$$a^{\log_b n} = (b^{\log_b a})^{\log_b n}$$
$$= b^{\log_b a \log_b n} = (b^{\log_b n})^{\log_b a}$$
$$= n^{\log_b a}.$$

The first and last "=" following from the fact that $d = c^{\log_c d}$ for any $c,d>1$, and the remaining "=" following from the fact that the equation $e^{fg} = (e^f)^g$ holds for all positive ,,.

Answer (score -1):

I would just note that $n = a^{\log_a n}$ and $b=a^{\log_a b}$.

Then you have

$$n^{\log_a b} =( a^{\log_a n})^{\log_a b}.$$

While

$$b^{\log_a n} = (a^{\log_a b})^{\log_a n}.$$

By the rules of exponents, the two right sides are equal.